# How to hold further request until my function is completed and then resume back request queue in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a newbie to scrapy and python. I am working with scrapy 0.17.0 .
I have set crawler on a website which send's me a captcha page after a number of request's. I have set 10 concurrent request. Now when I get captcha the page I want to hold further request's until I download the captcha image and solve it.

Once my captcha is solved I want to resume my request queue. But I dont know how to pause request queue.
I have added sleep time when I get 302 status(which is a page for captcha) but that is not working.

below is my settings.py

```
    BOT_NAME = 'testBot'
    SPIDER_MODULES = ['testCrawler.spiders']
    NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'testCrawler.spiders'

    CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 10
    CONCURRENT_SPIDERS = 5

    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
    COOKIES_ENABLED = 'false'

    # SET USER AGENTS LIST
    USER_AGENTS = ['Mozilla/4.0  (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; BTRS106490)',
                'Mozilla/4.0  (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C)',
                'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)',
                'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0']

    PROXIES = ['http://192.168.100.225:8123']

    DOWNLOADDELAYLIST = ['3', '4', '6', '5']

    RETRY_TIMES = 20
    RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504, 400, 408, 302]
```

here is my crawler

```
    import time
    import re
    from scrapy.http import Request
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
    from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from testCrawler.items import linkItem
    from testCrawler.imageItems import linkImageItem

    class CategorySpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = 'categoryLink'
        allowed_domains = ['somedomail.com']
        start_urls = ['http://somesite.com/topsearches']

        def parse(self, response):
            self.state['items_count'] = self.state.get('items_count', 0) + 1
            self.logCaptchaPages(response.status, response.url)

            hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
            catLinks = hxs.select('//div[@class="topsearcheschars"]/a/@href').extract()

            for catLink in catLinks:
                if re.match('(.*?)/[0-9]+$', catLink):
                    continue
                else:
                    yield Request(catLink, callback=self.alphaDetailPage)

        def alphaDetailPage(self, aResponse):
            self.logCaptchaPages(aResponse.status, aResponse.url)
            hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(aResponse)
            pageLinks = hxs.select('//div[@class="topsearcheschars"]/a/@href').extract()
            dtlLinks = hxs.select('//div[@class="topsearches"]/a/@href').extract()

            for dtlLink in dtlLinks:
                yield Request(dtlLink, callback=self.listPageLinks)

            for pageLink in pageLinks:
                if re.match('(.*?)/[0-9]+$', pageLink):
                    yield Request(pageLink,callback=self.pageDetail)

        def pageDetail(self, bResponse):
            self.logCaptchaPages(bResponse.status, bResponse.url)
            hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(bResponse)
            dtlLinks = hxs.select('//div[@class="topsearches"]/a/@href').extract()

            for dtlLink in dtlLinks:
                yield Request(dtlLink, callback=self.listPageLinks)

        def listPageLinks(self, lResponse):
            self.logCaptchaPages(lResponse.status, lResponse.url)
            hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(lResponse)
            similarSearchLinks = hxs.select('//a[@class="similar_search"]/@href').extract()

            if len(similarSearchLinks) > 0:
                for i in range(len(similarSearchLinks)):
                    yield Request(similarSearchLinks[i], callback=self.listPageLinks)

            itm = linkItem()
            titleList = hxs.select('//div[@id="h1-wrapper"]/h1/text()').extract()

            if len(titleList) > 0:
                itm['url'] = lResponse.url
                itm['title'] = titleList[0]
                yield itm
            else:
                yield

        def logCaptchaPages(self, statusCode, urlToLog):
            if statusCode == 302:
                yield Request(urlToLog, callback=self.downloadImage)
                time.sleep(10)

        def downloadImage(self, iResponse):
            hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(iResponse)
            imageUrl = hxs.select('//body/img/@src').extract()[0]
            itm = linkImageItem()
            itm['url'] = iResponse.url
            itm['image_urls'] = [imageUrl]
            yield itm
```

Currently I am testing with just a captcha image download and once it works I plan to call other function's which will send a request tothe captcha page with captcha text. Once that captcha page is passed I want to deal with the next request.

Any ideas about why its not working?

May be I am doing wrong in that case can anyone point where it is going wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: I think it would help to solve your issue if you told exactly what happens when the `logCaptachePages` is called (*ie* elaborate on *I have added sleep time when I get 302 status(which is a page for captcha) but that is not working.*)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to swap `time.sleep(10)` and `yield Request(urlToLog, callback=self.downloadImage)` in the `logCaptchaPages` method so that your request is returned *after* the 10 seconds pause.

```
def logCaptchaPages(self, statusCode, urlToLog):
    if statusCode == 302:
        print "Got CAPTCHA page"
        time.sleep(10)
        yield Request(urlToLog, callback=self.downloadImage)
```